# Is it possible to attach an existing block of memory to a file using mmap

Tags: c++, mmap

I have a block of memory which I have allocated using mmap.  I then want to write this block of memory to a file on the file system.  I am wondering if there is a way to point the existing block of memory directly to a file descriptor using mmap() or will I have to copy the whole block of memory to a new mmap() area which has been created with the file descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vmsplice` with `SPLICE_F_GIFT` to place the memory into a pipe, after that `splice` or `copy_file_range` may do what is required.

Answer (score 0):

You will have top copy it, unless you can create the `mmap` with a temporary file in the first place, and then just rename the file when you want to "save" it.

I'm not familiar with all implementations, I have looked quite closely at the Linux implementation, but I believe this applies in all cases: When you do not have a file when you create a `mmap` region, the OS will use the "swap" as a `file` for the `mmap` region. Since there is a mapping between the file-content and the memory content, you can't trivially just change what that mapping is (although it could, perhaps, be technically possible to achieve, it could be rather "expensive" if you have a 4GB `mmap` region, where only a small part of it is in physical RAM, the rest is "on disk").

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking pure POSIX, there's no way to attach an `mmap`'d region to a new fd. I'm also not aware of any way to do this in Linux or OS X.

You'll have to either copy, or `mmap` the file that you want to write to in the first place. If you don't want the file to appear immediately for some reason, there's the following workaround:

- `open` a temporary file in the filesystem where you want the final file (the same directory is a safe bet)
- `mmap` it, modify it, write out changes
- `rename` the file to its final location.